# Rename and reconfigure Content services in SDL Web 8

Tags: web8, content-delivery, odata, microservices, content-service

Recently we have upgraded CMS environment from SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 to SDL Web 8.1.1. In SDL Web 8.1.1 http://domain:port/Content.svc and Preview.svc seems replacement for OData.svc as content service. My question is whether we can rename http://domain:port/Content.svc and Reconfigure its ports so that it can be replicated as http://domain:port/Odata.svc. The main reason for this requirement is our client is consuming http://domain:port/OData.svc in many live applications and they are not able to change the service reference in their live applications.

Regards